# What is the situation we have to use docusing brand destination url and docusing webhook?

Tags: docusignapi

My application wants to send an email to signer for signing DocuSign (remote signing using DocuSign rest api) and after completing signing, the website should get the update that the envelope is signed and update the database.

So can I set the brand destination URL, so that the website will get the envelope Id in the merge field and we can update the database?

In this scenario do we need to use a webbook or set a brand destination URL as I said earlier?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please, check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after completing signing, the website should get the update that the envelope is signed and update the database.

Best way to handle this is to use a DocuSign webhook. You have two options:

- Use the Connect Webhook feature for an account-level webhook. This will send a notification to your server (your "listener") anytime any application in the account, for any user, sends an envelope. You can set which users will trigger a notification and which events (eg envelope_sent, envelope_completed) etc.

The webhook configuration is defined for the account using the eSign settings application or via the API.

- Use the eventNotification attribute of the Envelopes:create API call. You get basically the same options as the account-level webhook, but for just one envelope. You define the webhook's settings when you make the API call to send the envelope.

Here's a [live example via the API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Webhook%20JSON%20notification%20format%20with%20metadata%20). You can configure the example with a webhook listener URL from [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) or from similar services.